Using VBScript Function "FindLabel" is not displaying the labels on Mobile Map Application
I created a Map with layers in Pro, one of the layers I used VBScript Function "FindLabel", when I created a Mobile Map App the labels of this layer is not showing on the MMPK file.
I tried using both VSBScript and Python. Labels are working perfectly fine on the Map in Pro but not showing in the MMPK file?
The VBSscript:
Function FindLabel ([FACILITYID],[INTERVAL])
If [FACILITYID]="2IPO1.00345" Or [FACILITYID] ="2B1.0159A9" Or [FACILITYID]="2B1.00617" Or [FACILITYID]="2B1.00616" Then 
Findlabel = [INTERVAL] + " Days Interval - VAC Only"
ElseIf [FACILITYID]="2VS3.00135" Then 
Findlabel = [INTERVAL] + " Days Interval - DO NOT SET UP IN FRONT OF HOUSE"
Else Findlabel = [INTERVAL] + " Days Interval"
End If
End Function

The Python Script:
def FindLabel([INTERVAL], [FACILITYID]):
    if str([FACILITYID]) == "2IPO1.00345": 
        return "{} Days Interval - VAC Only".format([INTERVAL])
    elif str([FACILITYID]) == "2B1.0159A":
        return "{} Days Interval - VAC Only".format([INTERVAL])
    elif str([FACILITYID]) == "2VS3.00135":
        return "{} Days Interval - DO NOT SET UP IN FRONT OF 222 ETHEL ST HOUSE".format([INTERVAL])
    else:
        return "{} Days Interval".format([INTERVAL])


What did you try?
